# Python: Trying to use polymorphism with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to use polymorphism in my pygame project but I keep  getting errors.

I have a Moveable class and a Objects class that inherits from Moveable and I get an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ypos' in my game loop.

I plan on having more moveable objects in my project like people, houses, road signs... if i can get this working.

```
class Moveable:
    __name = ""
    __xpos = 0
    __ypos = 0
    __hight = 0
    __width = 0
    __speed = 0
    __image = 0

    def __init__(self, xpos, ypos, hight, width, speed, image):
        self.__xpos = xpos
        self.__ypos = ypos
        self.__hight = hight
        self.__width = width
        self.__image = image

    def set_xpos(self, xpos):
        self.__xpos = xpos

    def get_xpos(self):
        return self.__xpos

    # ... and all my other getters and setters...


class Objects(Moveable):

    def car(xpos, ypos, width, hight, speed, image):
        pygame.Surface.blit(gameDisplay, image, [xpos, ypos, hight, width])

def game_loop():

game_exit = False #sets the game loop to false

while not game_exit: # runs the game loop until the game exit = true

    car = Objects.car(random.randrange(250, 550), -400, 60, 70, 4, pygame.image.load('car.png'))
    gameDisplay.blit(backGroundImg, (0, 0)) #displays the background
    car.ypos += car.speed # the error is here **********
```

r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the pygame if that is your intent.

```
def car(xpos, ypos, width, hight, speed, image):
    return pygame.Surface.blit(gameDisplay, image, [xpos, ypos, hight, width])
```

As it stands, `car` has no return statement, so assigning a variable to the method will return `None`, hence your error trying to access an attribute on a `NoneType`

Comment: wow lol thanks, can't believe i missed that... i got an entirely new error (AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'ypos') but i should be able to figure it out. Thank you!